# Multiple IPFS peers on the same machine

Tags: ipfs

I am trying to setup multiple IPFS peers on the same Windows machine, in order to test file sharing and pubsub service.

I have created a different .ipfs folder for each peer, that is .ipfs1, .ipfs2.
In each config file i have replaced the ports **4001**, **5001** and **8080** to not overlap.

So when i want to run all the daemons at the same time i open 2 console windows and input in each one:

```
set IPFS_PATH=C:\Users\MyName\.ipfsX (X = the peer number)
ipfs daemon --enable-pubsub-experiment
```

When i want to execute commands in a specific peer i open a new console window and type:

```
set IPFS_PATH=C:\Users\MyName\.ipfsX (X = the peer number)
cmd
```

So let's get to the problem. I want to run 2 peers, subscribe both to the same pubsub channel and exchange messages.

I have 6 open console windows, 3 for each peer:

- 1 for the running daemon
- 1 for executing sub and listening for messages
- 1 for inputing commands

The issue is that when i send a pubsub message, only the same peer receives it.
Only Peer1 listens to messages created by Peer1, etc.

Is there something wrong with my multi-peer setup? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: After some more digging i see that webui is not working either, on ports other than the default 5001.
When both Peer1 and Peer2 daemons are running, http://127.0.0.1:5001/webui works, but http://127.0.0.1:5002/webui keeps loading forever.
Maybe the port numbers are hardcoded somewhere and changing them in config is not enough for multiple peers.
Am i missing something, or virtualization is the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to use docker or VMs, the setup you described is very likely to cause issues. Try doing `ipfs swarm peers` to see if your nodes are connected to any of the peers.